# 404 when accessing new route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to add a new route (/profile) to my NodeJS Express web application. I've modified my `app.js` file like this:

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var profile = require('./routes/profile');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/profile', profile);
```

The '/' index path works fine, my issue is with '/profile'. Whenever I try to access it, I get a 404. This is profile.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/profile', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.session.username;

    if(username) {
        res.render('profile');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong because in the example express application that is generated, '/users' works fine. I basically copied that format, but it's throwing a 404. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In my `profile.js`, I had to change my `GET` request path to this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //code
});
```

Otherwise, the `router` would be looking for `/profile/profile`. When I change it to `/`, it's just looking for the root of `/profile', or at least that's how I understand it.

Answer (score -1):

To understand what you are doing wrong you should know that Node.js uses middleware functions to route your requests. To simplify you can think about it as a **chain of functions**.

> Middleware is like a plumbing pipe, requests start at the first middleware you define and work their way “down” the middleware stack processing for each path they match.

So with the following statement you added a middleware function to handle any request starting with the root path `/profile`, and it is a common pattern in Node to use the `use` method to define the root paths.

```
app.use('/profile', profile);
```

The use method is doing part of the routing in your scenario and the statement above will match any route starting with that path, including `/profile/all` or `/profile/12` or even `/profile/go/deeper/inside`.

However, you want to narrow down that routing to something more specific, so that is why you pass a router middleware function (`profile` in your case) to match more specific routes instead of all routes starting with `/profile`.

The `profile` middleware function is actually the next step in the chain of functions to execute, and it will start from the root path specified in the `use` statement, which is the reason why you need to start again with `/` and not with `/profile`. If you wanted to match a profile by ID you would do:

```
router.get('/:id', ...)
```

Which would be concatenated with the base URL (from the /use statement) and would match a request like `/profile/2` or `/profile/abc`.